# built in method for retrieving csrf token

Tags: java, spring-security, csrf

I have enabled csrf in **Spring Security 3.2.9.RELEASE**.  I have found on the web these options for obtaining the csrf token:

[include token is http response headers](https://www.codesandnotes.be/2015/02/05/spring-securitys-csrf-protection-for-rest-services-the-client-side-and-the-server-side/)

OR

manually create a GET api to retrieve it

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/csrf")
    public @ResponseBody String retrieveCsrfToken(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        if (null != request.getSession(false)) {
            System.out.println("session exist ");
        }
        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        return token.getToken();
    }
```

Is there no built in mechanism to retrieve it?
What is the intended default way to obtain the token?

All other csrf functionality is already coded/built in (by spring) except for this one piece of how to obtain the token.  I feel like I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring-security-web` module allows to access the CSRF token in a view by referencing `$_csrf` parameter. As per [6.4.3. Include the CSRF Token docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token) this can be done as part of form submission:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

or stored in `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

for further reading through JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
  var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
  var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
  });
});
```